# Using javascript fetch with web service not working

Tags: javascript, java, http, server

So I'm trying to make a webservice that allows someone to obtain data from a server. Right now, the server I'm using is written using java's HttpServer class. I plan to make the server accessible using fetch() in javascript, but it's not working.

When I was first testing out my server, I used Apache's HttpComponents library, and that client(written in java). was able to receive the test json that came from my server. However, when I used fetch() on my javascript client, nothing is received when I console.log everything. It doesn't make sense to me why it would work in Java, but not javascript. Does anyone know why this is not working? Am I just doing the javascript part wrong, and it does actually work? Thanks!

Code snippets for reference:

java server:

```
public class Main {
    private static final int PORT = 1337;
    private static final int BACKLOG = 1;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(PORT), BACKLOG);
            System.out.print("started on" + PORT);
            HttpContext context = server.createContext("/ex", new Handler());
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Handler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("handled");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
        obj.put("name", "value");
        obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
        obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
        obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));
        obj.put("array", new int[]{1, 2, 3});
        String response = obj.toJSONString();
        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        he.getResponseBody().write(response.getBytes());

    }

}
```

java client:

```
public class PostTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:1337/ex");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println("STATUS LINE");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
        System.out.println("HEADER");
        Header[] h = response.getAllHeaders();
        for(int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(h[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("ENTITY.CONTENT");
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"))) {
            String s;
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Javascript:

```
var init = {mode: "no-cors"};
    async function f() {
        return fetch("http://localhost:1337/ex", init).then(res => res.text()).then(posts => console.log(posts));
    }
    f();
```